# Confused about array.shift() - example from Secrets of the JS Ninja

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja and I'm stuck on some syntax within a code example. If you have the book, the code can be found on page 17 but a sample of it is below.

```
function runTest() {
  if (!paused && queue.length) {
    queue.shift()();
    if(!paused) {
      resume();
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody explain what's going on in line 3? What does `queue.shift()();` do? I've looked through the documentation on MDN and I've played with it a little in JSFiddle but I can't seem to figure it out. I suspected it may remove the first two elements from an array but that didn't work and the code example doesn't run without the second set of `()`.

If more code is needed to make sense of this, please let me know and I can add more.

Comment: `shift` apparently returns a function when invoked, so the first `()` invokes `shift` and the second `()` invokes the function that was returned. `function foo() { alert("foo"); return funtion() { alert("bar"); } }` ... `foo()()`

Comment: queue is array of function and queue.shift() return first element from queue and () execute the function

Comment: @Anoop _return_ or remove?

Comment: @BatuZet Sorry, remove and return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shift` removes the first object in an array, and *shifts* all objects up in the array.

The object which was removed is then returned.

In your example, the object must be a function which itself is then invoked.

This is shorthand for:

```
var removedFunc = queue.shift();
removedFunc();
```

---

See MDN documentation for more info on `shift`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns
>   that element. This method changes the length of the array.

---

**Example** (<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/792rQ/)</kbd>):

```
var a = [];

a.push(function(){
 alert("a");   
});

a.push(function(){
 alert("b");   
});

a.shift()(); //alerts a
a.shift()(); //alerts b
```

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`queue` is apparently an array of functions. The first function on the queue is being `shift()`ed off (ie. returned and removed from the array), and then immediately invoked.

If it helps, try:

```
var nextFunction = queue.shift();
nextFunction();
```

It's the same thing, just broken down for readability - certainly, I would instinctively see `()()` as a typo.

EDIT: You can also make it look "less typo-y" like so:

```
queue.shift().call();
```

In this way you are explicitly calling the function - again, it does the exact same thing, but now it looks deliberate.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now even if it is a little hard to trace through the code. But like you mentioned, I thought it was a typo as well which was why I started playing with the method to see what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) See my edit for another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

`shift()` gets the first value in an array, and if that value is a function, it can be called like any function

```
var queue = [ // array containing a function
    function() {
        alert('foo');
    }
]

queue.shift()(); // alerts foo
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5eDv/)

the same example written more verbose

```
var queue = [ // array containing a function
    function() {
        alert('foo');
    }
]

var fn = queue.shift();

fn();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `queue` is an Array.

[`Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element of an array and returns it. So if `queue` is an array of functions it executes the first function of the array and removes it.

```
var a = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

var b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}
var queue = [a, b];
queue.shift()(); // logs 'a'
queue.shift()(); // logs 'b'
console.log(queue.length) // logs 0
```